# Url maps operation in Django

Tags: django, django-views

i'm new to django and i'd like to know how the url maps work in detail.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from polls import views

urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index')

]
```

the url function takes 3 parameters, could you explain how they work and what functionalies they have.

I've searched for this, but no detailed information are available for an absolute beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Django URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/) contains `urlpatterns` which is a Python list of `url()` instances.

The [**url**(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.url) function can take 4 arguments:

- `regex`: Regular expression, pattern matching the url.
- `view`: View name, path, function or the result of [as_view()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) for class-based views. It can also be an [include()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.include).
- `kwargs`: Allows you to pass additional arguments to the view function or method.
- `name`: [Naming](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) URL patterns.

Comment: what is the regular expressions for ?

Comment: [Intro to Django url() regexes](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_urls/#regex)